# Inspect App State/Local State in Flutter DevTools

Tags: flutter

I'm using the VSCode Debugger (breakpoints) to peek into my states. I know there's a Flutter Devtools to Inspect the widget tree but I was not able to inspect data from it. Is there any better way of doing this like React/Redux Devtools? I'm using Scoped Models by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#faq) package which is devtools friendly